# How to manage same named constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Check my controller code bellow. The thing is i am using first `AccountController` to access my database context and second one want to access of my appsettings.json file with IConfiguration. But C# not giving to to name same named controller. So how can i access IConfiguration and database context at a time on same Controller file? Please note: I am using .net core mvc 2.1 Picture attached with error. Thanks in advance

[image: pic]

Controller code:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public AppDataCtx DataCtx { get; }
        public AccountController(AppDataCtx DataCtx)
        {
            this.DataCtx = DataCtx;
        }

        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        public IConfiguration AccountController(IConfiguration Configuration) 
        {
            _configuration = Configuration;
        }
}
```

Comment: You can use just `public AccountController(AppDataCtx DataCtx, IConfiguration Configuration) { DataCtx = DataCtx; _configuration = Configuration; }` as the constructor

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke i already tried and this works!

Comment: @johnCogdle as a side note and for a little more information, your second "constructor" isn't actually a constructor since it is returning a `IConfiguration`. It's certainly possible to have 2 constructors but they need to actually be constructors. Having a method named the same as the class that contains it ends up being a compiler error which is what you're seeing here